# Java; Accessing Member Instance Variables From Another Class

Tags: java, variables, class

I have the following structure:

```
public class A {
     private javax.swing.JLabel fullName;

     public class B {
             public B() {
                    fullName.setText("Martha Stewart");
             }
     }
     ...
     ...
     ...
}
```

My goal is to have B (currently the sub class of A) to be in a separate class.

The problem is: When I separate the two classes, I lose functionality on the .setText() call for the JLabel.  I realize that if B is in a separate class, I would have to write a public setter method in class A.

This, however, is not plausible since I have about 100 buttons and use 4-5 different functions for each button.  Creating a getter/setter method for each function is not plausible IMHO.

I'm trying to wrap my head around a better solution... can any of you help, friends?

Comment: Why do you want to remove it as a subclass?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to set the label text in a separate class? Could you just create a method that took a JLabel and a String, and called setText on that label object? Then, class A could pass in it's JLabel object and it would be modified outside of class A. (Not sure I understand your intention, so not sure if that qualifies as an answer.)

Comment: Class B does specific tasks for certain "tab groups" in my GUI, and there are many more like it.  

For ex:
  I have a simulator with 5 modules.  Each module is a subclass.  Each subclass does something specific in the GUI.

Comment: @Dante617 - If I passed the JLabel and a string from Class A to Class B, wouldn't that mean a "copy of the Jlabel" would be made and the resulting label will not have access?

Comment: Since fullName in this case is an object (JLabel) you're essentially passing a reference to the object. If you call a method on that object that changes it's state, the object held by Class A would have a different state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B *isn't* a subclass of A. It's a *nested* (inner) class within A.

However, you shouldn't try to get access to fields of other types - it breaks encapsulation. Properties are a nicer solution - or alternatively, a `setFullNameText` method which calls `fullName.setText()` itself. Just because you have 100 buttons (ouch!) doesn't mean it's time to throw encapsulation out of the window. It does mean you might want to consider grouping those 100 fields into smaller classes though...

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is there a way to autogenerate getter/setters or must I individually do it one by one?

Comment: An IDE like Eclipse can generate all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't let a class modify the attribute of another class, this breaks encapsulation. If you can't stand getters and setters, I'd suggest a configuration object (like a map), which could be given to the constructor and/or a setter of your main GUI class.

By the way:

> I have about 100 buttons

I think it's a main issue. You should break your GUI in several classes representing groups of controls.